# Problem integrating Travis CI and Unity on GitHub

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, travis-ci

I followed the instructions from this [link](https://github.com/kevinta893/unity3d-travis-ci) to integrate Travis CI in Unity

Unfortunately it seems that the build fails, next you can find anything I added to GitHub for this integration.
PS: I'm fairly a newbie to CI.

travis.yml file

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode9.2
rvm:
- 2.2         #see before_install for getting RVM stable.

env:
- TRAVIS_TAG="Deploy-2019.3.4f1" PROJECT_NAME="DungeonToolGeneration" UNITY_PROJECT_PATH="" DEPLOY_UNITYPACKAGE="path set in deploy script"


cache:
  directories:
    - $UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE

    
before_install:
- chmod a+x ./travis-build/*.sh

install:
- cat /etc/hosts
- ./travis-build/install-unity.sh

script:
- ./travis-build/build.sh
- ./travis-build/run-tests.sh

after_success:
- ./travis-build/export-unity-package.sh

before_deploy:
- DEPLOY_UNITYPACKAGE="$(ls -a release/*.zip | head -n 1)"

deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  file: $DEPLOY_UNITYPACKAGE
  skip_cleanup: true
  overwrite: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

install_unity files that i Edited to change the version to be tha same of the project

```
#! /bin/sh

# See https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
# to get download URLs
UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE="$(pwd)/unity_download_cache"
UNITY_OSX_PACKAGE_URL="https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/4f139db2fdbd/MacEditorInstaller/Unity.pkg"
UNITY_WINDOWS_TARGET_PACKAGE_URL="https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/4f139db2fdbd/MacEditorTargetInstaller/UnitySetup-Windows-Mono-Support-for-Editor-2019.3.4f1.pkg"


# Downloads a file if it does not exist
download() {

    URL=$1
    FILE=`basename "$URL"`
    
    # Downloads a package if it does not already exist in cache
    if [ ! -e $UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE/`basename "$URL"` ] ; then
        echo "$FILE does not exist. Downloading from $URL: "
        mkdir -p "$UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE"
        curl -o $UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE/`basename "$URL"` "$URL"
    else
        echo "$FILE Exists. Skipping download."
    fi
}

# Downloads and installs a package from an internet URL
install() {
    PACKAGE_URL=$1
    download $1

    echo "Installing `basename "$PACKAGE_URL"`"
    sudo installer -dumplog -package $UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE/`basename "$PACKAGE_URL"` -target /
}



echo "Contents of Unity Download Cache:"
ls $UNITY_DOWNLOAD_CACHE

echo "Installing Unity..."
install $UNITY_OSX_PACKAGE_URL
install $UNITY_WINDOWS_TARGET_PACKAGE_URL
```

[Travis Log](https://api.travis-ci.com/v3/job/470139663/log.txt)

TLDR LOG

```
    Items in project path (/Users/travis/build/ZarakiKanzaki/DungeonToolGeneration/):

Assets          ProjectSettings     travis-build

Packages        README.md       unity_download_cache

Building project for Windows...

[LicensingClient] ERROR Failed to connect to local IPC

[Licensing::Module] Failed to connect to channel: LicenseClient-travis

Launching external process: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/UnityLicensingClient.app/Contents/Resources/Unity.Licensing.Client

[Licensing::Module] Successfully launched the LicensingClient

[Licensing::Module] Successfully connected to LicensingClient on channel: LicenseClient-travis

[Licensing::Module] Successfully launched and connected to LicensingClient

Entitlement-based licensing initiated

[LicensingClient] Licenses Updated successfully in LicensingClient

DisplayProgressbar: Unity license

[UnityConnectServicesConfig] config is NOT valid, switching to default

[Licensing::Module] License is not active (com.unity.editor.headless). HasEntitlements will fail.

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0

Cancelling DisplayDialog: Failed to activate/update license Missing or bad username or password. Please try again using valid credentials or contact support@unity3d.com

This should not be called in batch mode. 

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Platform/OSX/EditorUtility.mm Line: 288)

Building Windows exe completed successfully.

Finishing with code 0

The command "./travis-build/build.sh" exited with 0.

0.05s$ ./travis-build/run-tests.sh

Skipping testing. No Tests implemented yet...

The command "./travis-build/run-tests.sh" exited with 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and it seems is a matter of credentials, I'm currently investiganting if it's possible to do a deployment with a normal license.

Currently the deployment on my pipeline is suspended.

Comment: Did you figure it out?